# Forge java Modding adding mysql-connector-java to a Mod

Tags: java, minecraft, mysql-connector, minecraft-forge

I've been trying for 2 weeks to add a dependency to my Forge mod which connects my client to my SQL server, in the IDE it finds the server but not in the client with the built mod.

Therefore, I would be happy if some of you could help me as a last hope.

Here is my Total gradle.build: https://pastebin.com/7QTGFdDT

I already tried adding **com.github.johnrengelman.shadow** to load the packages in the mod as well, but failed or did something wrong.

```java
try {
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "User", "Password");
            String sql = "INSERT INTO chat_messages (Test) VALUES (?)";
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setString(1, Test);
 statement.executeUpdate();
            statement.close();
 } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

That is what i tried so far, it would be nice of someone could help me.

---

What's the error you receive?
https://pastebin.com/HT5uPrrx

Did you run the "shadowJar" command?
Yes quite a lot of Times, with Different Options

Comment: What's the error you receive?

Comment: Did you run the "shadowJar" command?